# Triggering SettingWithCopyWarning even with loc

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a conforming Pandas code:

```
    def _set_filter_date(self, partition: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:

        partition_size = len(partition.index)
        filter_date = partition.date.iloc[partition_size-1]

        for i in range(0,partition_size):
            partition.loc[i,'filter_date'] = filter_date #<-- this is the important line

        return partition
```

Without dwelling into business logic details, the important line is the one assigning a value with .loc. This is not supposed to raise a `SettingWithCopyWarning` because it is not chaining any selection.
Why then it always raises this warning in output:

```
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  partition.loc[i,'filter_date'] = filter_date
/datapump/query_functions.py:248: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

Comment: Adding `partition = partition.copy()` before the for loop made the warning go away, but it feels like I am fooling the check, rather than really doing something differently.

Comment: Perhaps this is what's mentioned in the [pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) as "Sometimes a SettingWithCopy warning will arise at times when there’s no obvious chained indexing going on. These are the bugs that SettingWithCopy is designed to catch! pandas is probably trying to warn you that you’ve done this:"   Then an example of a df passed into a function, just like your case.